# Keep a large string in memory

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the following java code:

```
Path path = Paths.get("largefile.txt2");
if (Files.exists(path))
   exchange.getIn().setBody(Files.lines(path, Charset.forName("UTF-8")).map(row -> row + System.lineSeparator()).collect(Collectors.joining()).trim()); 
//OOM error!
```

I essentially need to read the entire file in memory to do various regex processing and splitting based on some search critera. The files can be as large as 300 MB - 1GB large.

The problem I have as that this works for files around 100 MB but once it reaches 200 or more I get out of memory error at `.setBody(..)` related to heap size.

Is there a more efficient and especially less memory consuming approach? Memory is more important for me than speed. Or do I need to rethink my entire approach and read piece by piece?

Comment: "less memory consuming approach" don't keep the string in memory, don't use regex.  Maybe a parser would work?

Comment: I could perhaps get away with not keeping the string in memory though that would mean starting over. I am still forced to use regex as I need to "clean" the data due to various parameters. What kind of parsers are you referring to?

Comment: With large data you need a stream-based approach, meaning you only hold a small window of data in memory at any time. I think your real problem is having to call `setBody()` with one massive string. You need to find a way to send the output piecemeal to `exchange`.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably not help too much, maybe let you work with a file a little bigger. You're creating many more Strings then required, by using things like:

`row + System.lineSeparator()` and `.trim()` on the end. You can probably use a lot less memory by changing your code a bit to:

```
exchange.getIn().setBody(Files.lines(path, Charset.forName("UTF-8")).collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
```

Although I don't quite understand why you're reading the file line by line and then joining the lines once again with a line separator.

Also to process a large file with regex it maybe useful to use the `Scanner` class and use the Scanner's `findWithinHorizon` method with a sufficiently large horizon for your needs. The scanner will advance automatically as matches are retrieved.